# Get min,max,argmin,argmax of (X,Y) coordinates in a vectorized way

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, vector

I have a list of coordinate vectors (x,y) as follows:

```
coord=[[3,6],
[7,9],
[14,9],
[11,8],
[3,1],
[7,14],
[19,30]
]
```

What I want to get ?

1. Get the min values from x coordinates then print the given (x,y) vector
2. Get the max values from x coordinates then print the given (x,y) vector
3. Get the min values from y coordintates then print the given (x,y) vector
4. Get the max values from y coordintates then print the given (x,y) vector
5. Get the min values from x coordintates and the min value from y coordinates then print the given (x,y) vector (in other term the smallest vector)
6. Get the max values from x coordintates and the max value from y coordinates then print the given (x,y) vector (in other term the largest vector)

What is the efficient and vectorized way to do that?

Comment: Please, share your code to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score -1):

First, convert your nested `list` into a NumPy array:

```
coord = np.array(coord)
```

Now you can get a 1D array of x-values by `coord[:,0]` and the y-values by `coord[:, 1]`. Using the `np.argmin` and `np.argmax` functions to get the index of the min/max value, you can do e.g.

```
xmin_index = np.argmin(coord[:, 0])
xmin_coord = coord[xmin_index]
print(xmin_coord)  # The (x,y) pair with minimum x, (3,6)
```

Comment: It works only for one dimension. for example here min x value is 3, however l would like to return the vector of min x values corresponding to the min y value. For instance here we have [3,6] and [3,1] , we should return [3,1]  not [3,6

Comment: @eric I don't see what this has to do with the dimensionality. This gives `[3, 6]` because the minimum `x` value is `3` (which happens to occur twice) and the `np.argmin` returns the index of the first occurrence of the minimum element.

Comment: l was looking for the min of y that corresponds to min x. so we first seek the min x value then we get a list of vectors with (x_min, y) then we look at the min y

Answer (score -1):

Following the suggestion made by @jmd_dk l update it as follow :

```
coord = np.array(coord)
xmin_value=np.min(coord[:,0])
min_x_vectors = coordinates[np.where(coordinates[:, 0] == xmin_value)]
minimum = np.argmin(min_x_vectors[:, 1])
x0,y0=min_x_vectors[minimum]
```

this returns `[3,1]` rather than `[3,6]`